# I am using chartjs node canvas to render a chart however the graph options are being ignored

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

I am using Chart.js in node with Chart.js Node Canvas to render graphs and then saving them to disk using the following code:

```
const width = 400; //px
const height = 400; //px
const { ChartJSNodeCanvas } = require('chartjs-node-canvas');

const chartCallback = (ChartJS) => {
    ChartJS.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.borderWidth = 2;
};

const canvasRenderService = new ChartJSNodeCanvas({ width, height, chartCallback});

(async () => {
    const configuration = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Ravenclaw', 'Gryffindor', 'Hufflepuff', 'Slytherin'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'House Points',
                data: [serverpointsarray[0], serverpointsarray[1], serverpointsarray[2], serverpointsarray[3]],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,                                       
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    type: 'linear',
                    beginAtZero: true,
                }
            }
        }
    };

    const imageBuffer = await canvasRenderService.renderToBuffer(configuration);
    fs.writeFileSync(`./housepoints/graph.png`, imageBuffer);
    })();
```

(`serverpointsarray` is previously defined)
However changing anything in the options section makes no difference to the final rendered graph, I have looked through the Chart.js documentation and have tried to use `min`, `beginAtZero` and options to change colour however regardless of what I add it makes no difference to the rendered result - the options seem to just be ignored

[Rendered result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7NG3.png) the y axis is not starting at zero

The issue doesn't seem to be with the options themselves because when I use this exact graph in html within  the graph is rendered fine by the browser. Unless it's slightly different with chartjs-nodee-canvas?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the v3 syntax of chart.js while node canvas uses v2 of chart.js, the documentation of that can be found here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/